# [zbar]How to decode qr code which contains Chinese (utf-8) by ZBar?

Tags: utf-8, character, qr-code, zbar

I am using libZbar,it decode QR code is fast when i decode which QR is contained Chinese(GBK Character),but when decoding the QR which contains Chinese(UTF-8),it will return err language.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k77kD.jpg)

This is QR content "墨水好多EXij-/!?:;AEyv0008",but when i used libZbar to decode it shows"蠅ｨ豌ｴ螂ｽ螟哘Xij-/!?:;AEyv0008"  i found the"EXij..."->"Xij..." and then,i check some ways to deal with this problem,I checked libZbar source code /zbar-0.10/zbar/qrcode/qrdectxt.c,they saies change this code ISO8859-1 -> GB18030 or GB2312 ,but it can`t help me

```
/*This is the encoding the standard says is the default.*/   
        latin1_cd=iconv_open("UTF-8","ISO8859-1"); 
/*But this one is often used, as well.*/
         sjis_cd=iconv_open("UTF-8","SJIS"); 
/*This is a trivial conversion just to check validity without extra code.*/   
        utf8_cd=iconv_open("UTF-8","UTF-8");
```

My program is coding by Qt runing on linux,the normal Chinese(utf-8) is show well,  The Zbar has converted the content of utf8 encoding into other encoding formats. This is not the step I need, but I cannot comment this entire code. What can I do?

1. Modify this part of the code, but I don't quite understand where to modify this part of the code.
2. Convert the character after zbar conversion back to utf8, I tried it, iconv() call failed and return -1.

   int ret =0;
   iconv_t cd;
   cd = iconv_open("sjis","utf-8");//or ISO8859-1 to utf-8
   ret = iconv(cd, &input, &charInPutLen, &output, &charOutPutLen);
   iconv_close(cd);
   the zbar source code function:qr_code_data_list_extract_text in line 45

[enter link description here](https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar/blob/master/zbar/qrcode/qrdectxt.c)

Answer (score 0):

i build a c project with Qt,then a debug it by step.this qr code does not contain utf8 flag begin in head,so it will use enc_list to deal with text, just change index of enc_list[]  utf8_cd  -> first

`enc_list[2]=sjis_cd; enc_list[1]=latin1_cd; enc_list[0]=utf8_cd;`

```
 if(inleft>=3&&in[0]==(char)0xEF&&in[1]==(char)0xBB&&in[2]==(char)0xBF)
 {
                in+=3;
                inleft-=3;
 }
```